# How to pass country id to <a href> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, parameter-passing

I got the below code:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="showPartners.action?" id="_form" onsubmit="return selCheck();">
<div style="float: left; width: 350px;">
    <span class="text_vert"> Select Country : </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <s:select style="width:200px;" onchange="loadBusinessList();"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Country Select" list="couList"
    listKey="idCountry" listValue="label" id="countryId"
    name="countryId">
    </s:select>
</div>

<a href='addPartner.action?height=550&width=850&id=<s:property value="countryId"/>'" >Insert</a>
</form>
```

What I need to do is to pass the country ID to the link in the a href tag, but what I get is the ID=0.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use JavaScript, like so:

```
<s:select style="width:200px;" onchange="loadBusinessList();document.getElementById('anchor_id').href=document.getElementById('anchor_id').href.replace(/&id=(?:$|\d+)/, '&id=' + this.value)" ...
```

And:

```
<a id="anchor_id" href='addPartner.action?height=550&width=850&id=0'" >Insert</a>
```

Please note: the code assumes your countryIds are integers.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Your solution produces a link of: "http://localhost:8080/admin/addPartner.action?height=550&width=850148". The "id=" is lost. And once I have chosen the country and want to change the selection, the id is not updating for the second time. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

Best way it's to create a curl and use it.

```
<c:url value="addPartner.action" var="myAddPartnerUrl" scope="page">
<c:param name="height" value="550" />
<c:param name="width" value="850" />
<c:param name="id" value="${countryId}" />
</c:url>
```

html:

```
<a href="${myAddPartnerUrl}">
```

you can manage dinamically your url and no problem about syntax since c:url create the right string itself. More, you can use param for "addPartner.action" instead to put directly in c:url (same for rest of params).

[Link Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm)

Comment: This solution do not work too. Debugger sais: "pageContext.getExpressionEvaluator().evaluate("${myAddPartnerUrl}", java.lang.String.class, ((javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext) pageContext).getVariableResolver(), null) = >None of the "evaluate" methods in class "org.apache.jasper.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl" takes parameters of types "(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, org.apache.jasper.el.VariableResolverImpl, java.lang.Object)".<"

Comment: This gives "Unterminated <%@ taglib tag"

Comment: No luck, this gives the url with id=0 and id does not change when I change the dropdown value.

Comment: countryId it's assigned once that's why you can't manage to use it. Combine the method like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845862/set-id-of-select-options-to-jstl-variable so let countryId be dependant from your select

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the country id in a separate variable while changing the value in the select list and then pass that variable in the href link.